# In Code Blocks 13.12, how do I turn on real-time error checking?

Tags: codeblocks

I want Code Blocks to check my spelling and syntax as I type. For example, if I type

```
int myInt;
myint++;
```

Code Blocks should highlight myint as an error. Right now it doesn't inform me of the error until compiling.

The same error checking should occur with syntax; for example, forgetting a semicolon, or adding too many curly braces.

I am working in the C programming language.